# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. (google contacts api)

Tags: javascript, google-contacts-api

I am trying to get photo of google contact. from [api guide](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/?hl=en#retrieving_a_contacts_photo) found this:

`https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/photos/media/{userEmail}/{contactId}`

my code:

```
`$.get("https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/photos/media/default/54b8abe0f52ad02?access_token=" + authorizationResult.access_token + "&v=3.0",
        function(response){
          //process the response here
          console.log(response);
        }
      );`
```

it gives me this error:

**No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.**

but this seems to be working fine

```
`$.get("https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?alt=json&access_token=" + authorizationResult.access_token + "&max-results=500&v=3.0",
        function(response){
          //process the response here
          console.log(response);
        }
      );`
```

**Edit:**
full js script:

`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var clientId = 'my client id';
  var apiKey = 'api key';
  var scopes = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly';
  $(document).on("click",".googleContactsButton", function(){
    gapi.client.setApiKey(apiKey);
    window.setTimeout(authorize);
  });
  function authorize() {
    gapi.auth.authorize({client_id: clientId, scope: scopes, immediate: false}, handleAuthorization);
  }
  function handleAuthorization(authorizationResult) {
    if (authorizationResult && !authorizationResult.error) {
      $.get("https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/photos/media/default/54b8abe0f52ad02?access_token=" + authorizationResult.access_token + "&v=3.0",
        function(response){
          //process the response here
          console.log(response);
        }
      );
    }
  }
</script>
```

`

Comment: Are you creating proxy anywhere in your code..?

Comment: I have added the full script.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/features/cors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the picture by doing this: (prefix image url with proxy url)

```
`  function handleAuthorization(authorizationResult) {
    if (authorizationResult && !authorizationResult.error) {
      console.log(authorizationResult);
      var accessToken = authorizationResult.access_token;
      $.get("https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/thin?alt=json&access_token=" + accessToken + "&max-results=500&v=3.0",
        function(response){
          //process the response here
          console.log(response);
          let photoUrl = response.feed.entry[2].link[0].href + "&access_token=" + accessToken;
          let proxy = 'https://cors.now.sh/';
          let finalPhotoUrl = proxy + photoUrl;
          document.getElementById('photo').src = finalPhotoUrl;
        }
      );
    }
  }`
```